# Validating nested objects using class-validator in Nestjs

Tags: nestjs, class-validator

I am having difficulty with validating a nested object. Running nestJs using class-validator. The top level fields (first_name, last_name etc) validate OK. The Profile object is validated OK at the top level, ie if I submit as an array I get back the correct error that it should be an object.

The contents of Profile however are not being validated.  I have followed suggestions on the docs but maybe  I am just missing something.

Does anyone know how to validate nested object fields?

```
 export enum GenderType {
    Male,
    Female,
}

export class Profile {
    @IsEnum(GenderType) gender: string;
}

export class CreateClientDto {
    @Length(1) first_name: string;

    @Length(1) last_name: string;

    @IsEmail() email: string;

    @IsObject()
    @ValidateNested({each: true})
    @Type(() => Profile)
    profile: Profile; 
}
```

When I send this payload I expect it to fail because gender is not in the enum or a string. But it is not failing

```
{
   "first_name":"A",
   "last_name":"B",
   "profile":{
      "gender":1
   }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This will help:

```
export enum GenderType {
    Male = "male",
    Female = "female",
}

export class Profile {
    @IsEnum(GenderType) 
    gender: GenderType;
}

export class CreateClientDto {
    @IsObject()
    @ValidateNested()
    @Type(() => Profile)
    profile: Profile; 
}
```

P.S: You don't need `{each: true}` because it's an object not an array

Comment: this is what I have in my code. I have tried with {each:true} and without. Maybe I have an environment problem.

Comment: So let me ask it this way, what request are sending? What response are you receiving? What response do you expect to see? I still don't get what your problem is. Can you also post profile object in your code?

Comment: I have added sample payload. does class-validator not pick up enums ?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums

TS docs say to initialize the string enum.

So I needed to have:

```
export enum GenderType {
    Male = 'Male',
    Female = 'Female',
}
```

Comment: What you did is correct, `gender:  GenderType` is what it should be, not string!

Comment: Ooops! Now I know why this is happening! because enums are changed to number! unless you define an string for them! `gender: 1` is actually Female! and `gender: 0` is male cause its defined as the second element in your enum class! I edited my answer! check it again!